# Google Maps API v3: routeIndex Not Working?

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps API v3 and am trying to provide a "Show Next Route" button, where a user can cycle through all available routes.

I've got it displaying the first route, but when I use the routeIndex property of the DirectionsRenderer class, it only returns the first route.

Am I doing something wrong? Code pasted below. The test route I've been using has a total of three routes. If I set the routeIndex property to 1, it still displays the first route in the array (basically, routeIndex[0]).

```
function showDirections() {
// show contact buttons
$(".contact-route-button").css({display:"block"});

// add 1 to count
count++;

// If this function has been run before, clear the directions
if(count > 1){
    // Clear map
    directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
    //Clear Route List
    document.getElementById('directions').innerHTML = "";
}

// Set map to render directions
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map,
    /*preserveViewport: true,*/
    draggable: true,
    routeIndex: 1
});

// Remove hidden class form text explaning driving directions
$('#drive-text').fadeIn("fast").removeClass('hidden');

// Hide paragraph under directions form
$(".section.grids-two.maximum-780.clearfix .grid.grid-2").fadeOut("fast");

// SlideToggle panel about random fact
$(".random-fact").slideDown("fast").css({display:"block"});

// Set Panel that will display driving directions
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions'));

// Get address input text
var address = document.getElementById('dir-address').value;

// Create request to send to Google starting at the address provided
var request = {
    origin: address,
    destination: '531 E Market Street Indianapolis, IN 46204',
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.STANDARD,
    provideRouteAlternatives: true
};


// Send request and display on map and directions box
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        totalRoutes = countRoutes(response);
    }
});
}
```

Any ideas? The instructions I'm following are on the Google Maps API documentation, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the `routeIndex` does only have an effect when the `directions`-property is available in the directionsRenderer. You may use:

```
 directionsDisplay.setOptions({directions:response,routeIndex:1});
```

...what will set both, `directions` and `routeIndex`