# Can't draw route without changing map center and focus

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm doing a small web app in which I draw a set of different alternative routes between point A and point B using google-maps-api-3.
I need to be able to highlight each of them individually on a click event basis but i want to disable the automatic focus google maps does when you draw a route in the map.

Before setting the new data for each route, i first remove them from the map with:

```
for(var i=0; i < journeysContainer.JOURNEYS.length; i++) {
    directionsDisplayArray[i].setMap(undefined);
}
```

After that, i use this function in which i set the new DirectionsRenderer options for all my different routes:

```
function adjustRouteStroke(routeIndex) {
    var strokeWeight = 3;
    var strokeOpacity = 1;
    var color = '#707070';

    for(var i=0; i<directionsDisplayArray.length; i++) {
        directionsDisplayArray[i] = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            suppressMarkers: true,
            suppressInfoWindows: true,
            preserveViewport : true,
            routeIndex: 5,
            polylineOptions: {
                strokeOpacity: strokeOpacity,
                strokeColor: color,
                strokeWeight: strokeWeight
            },
            markerOptions: {
                icon : iconBaseURL + color
            }
        });
    }

    //highlight the selected route stroke
    strokeWeight = showBalloons?7:5;
    strokeOpacity = 1;
    color = '#1A00DC';

    directionsDisplayArray[routeIndex] = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        suppressMarkers: !showBalloons,
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        preserveViewport : true,
        routeIndex: 1,
        polylineOptions: {
            strokeOpacity: strokeOpacity,
            strokeColor: color,
            strokeWeight: strokeWeight
        },
        markerOptions: {
            icon : selectedMarkerIcon
        }
    });
}
```

After this i just redraw all the routes with code:

```
    for(var i=0; i < journeysContainer.JOURNEYS.length; i++) {
        if(i != routeIndex){
            directionsDisplayArray[i].setDirections(directionsResultArray[i]);
            directionsDisplayArray[i].setMap(map);
        }
    }

    directionsDisplayArray[routeIndex].setDirections(directionsResultArray[routeIndex]);
    directionsDisplayArray[routeIndex].setMap(map);
```

What am i doing wrong? I thought that the preserveViewport option was enough to avoid changing the current map focus and center.

Comment: preserveViewport should prevent the DirectionsRenderer from changing the maps viewport. Do you have a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem? Or  a [simple example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I don't know it this will help: anyway, you are calling `setMap(undefined)`, it should be `setMap(null)`.

Comment: I don't get the last block of code: that if statement seems unnecessary. And check answer to question [Google Maps API v3: routeIndex Not Working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303527/google-maps-api-v3-routeindex-not-working)

Comment: Thanks Anto, you were right on that. Unfortunately, it still does not solve the problem.

That if statement is something that i used because the routeIndex parameter that i'm using seems to not work 100%, this way i'm trying to avoid my highlighted route being "under" an alternative route.